# SQS FIFO failed to send a message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

What happens when a producer **fails** to send a message to the SQS queue? Is there any way to configure or retry to send that message again.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to send a message"? Do you mean that AWS did not successfully receive the request? If so, that is out-of-scope for AWS since the message was never received. It would be the responsibility of the producer to ensure that the message was received by SQS.

Answer (score 2):

Since Amazon SQS relies on Producer's "fire-and-forget" methodology, it makes Amazon SQS not responsible for retrying since Producer is the initiating. It is Producer's job to send the necessary message to SQS.

Retries in SQS is possible for Consumers which makes SQS responsible that the message has been processed.